# How to select records based on the max value of two fields?

Tags: mysql, groupwise-maximum

Given the following simple table:

```
+-----+-------------+---------+----+
| id_ | match_op_id | version | p1 |
+-----+-------------+---------+----+
|   1 |           1 |       1 |  1 |
|   2 |           1 |       1 |  5 |
|   3 |           1 |       2 |  3 |
|   4 |           1 |       2 |  4 |
|   5 |           2 |       1 |  1 |
|   6 |           2 |       1 |  5 |
|   7 |           2 |       2 |  3 |
|   8 |           2 |       2 |  4 |
|   9 |           2 |       2 |  4 |
+-----+-------------+---------+----+
```

I want to build a query that selects the `match_op_id` and `p1` fields for a single record (doesn't matter which one) for each `match_op_id` from the max `version` and then the max `p1`. So from the above I would get the output:

```
+-------------+----+
| match_op_id | p1 |
+-------------+----+
|           1 |  4 |
|           2 |  4 |
+-------------+----+
```

Following some posts on SO I've built a query that selects all records where the `p1` field is the maximum value:

```
SELECT 
    odds_op.match_op_id, odds_op.p1
FROM
    odds_op,
    (SELECT 
        match_op_id, MAX(p1) AS p1
    FROM
        odds_op
    GROUP BY match_op_id) AS max_p1
WHERE
    odds_op.match_op_id = max_p1.match_op_id
        AND odds_op.p1 = max_p1.p1
```

I now can't figure out how to ensure I only select the maximum `p1` from the maximum `version`. I think it's probably a nested sub query but I can't figure it out. I also know I'll run into some issues with grouping so that I don't end up with multiple records per `match_op_id`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expcted  result

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Are you looking for "groupwise-max"?  Or `ORDER BY .. LIMIT 1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For MySql 8.0+ you can do it with `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT match_op_id,
       FIRST_VALUE(p1) OVER (PARTITION BY match_op_id ORDER BY version DESC, p1 DESC) p1
FROM odds_op
```

For previous versions, use `NOT EXISTS` to filter the table, so that only rows with the max `version` of each `match_op_id` are returned and then aggregate to get the max `p1`:

```
SELECT o1.match_op_id, MAX(o1.p1) p1
FROM odds_op o1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM odds_op o2 
  WHERE o2.match_op_id = o1.match_op_id AND o2.version > o1.version
)
GROUP BY o1.match_op_id
```

Or with a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT o1.match_op_id, MAX(o1.p1) p1
FROM odds_op o1
WHERE o1.version = (SELECT MAX(o2.version) FROM odds_op o2 WHERE o2.match_op_id = o1.match_op_id)
GROUP BY o1.match_op_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=855a55303adcae713bc9782d296c1b9b).
Results:

> | match_op_id | p1 |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 4 |
> | 2 | 4 |

Answer (score 2):

You could use `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregation function that allows for sorting and take first element of created string:

```
SELECT match_op_id,  
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(p1 ORDER BY version DESC, p1 DESC SEPARATOR '~'),'~',1) AS p1
FROM odds_op
GROUP BY match_op_id;
```

Output(added GROUP_CONCAT as separate debug column):

```
+--------------+-----+-----------+
| match_op_id  | p1  |   debug   |
+--------------+-----+-----------+
|           1  |  4  | 4~3~5~1   |
|           2  |  4  | 4~4~3~5~1 |
+--------------+-----+-----------+
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=35c2eaa734c60c08eaf62813db77b445)**

---

If you are using MariaDB this is even simpler [using LIMIT clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66976376/5070879).

```
SELECT match_op_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(p1 ORDER BY version DESC, p1 DESC LIMIT 1) AS p1
FROM odds_op
GROUP BY match_op_id;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=dc9fdc1d84f3ba3bf35a80a30538a383)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not complete sure about you desire result.

You said: "I now can't figure out how to ensure I only select the maximum p1 from the maximum version."

This is a way:

```
SELECT MAX(p1)
FROM odds_op
WHERE version = (SELECT MAX(version) FROM odds_op);
```

If you want select match_op_id and p1 pairs where version is max version, and then p1 is max p1 (max p1 where version is max version), then check this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT match_op_id, p1
FROM odds_op
WHERE version = (SELECT MAX(version) FROM odds_op)
    AND p1 = (SELECT MAX(p1)
                FROM odds_op
                WHERE version = (SELECT MAX(version) FROM odds_op));
```

Try different responds with this values and check the results:

```
INSERT INTO odds_op (id_, match_op_id, version, p1) VALUES
  ('1', '1', '1', '1'),
  ('2', '1', '1', '5'),
  ('3', '1', '2', '3'),
  ('4', '1', '2', '4'),
  ('5', '2', '1', '1'),
  ('6', '2', '1', '5');
```

For my example data, my query return (It doesn't return pair: 2,5):

| match_op_id | p1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |

For your example data the result is the same you want.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit cheaty, and you would have to be certain you know the upper bound of your p1 values:

```
SELECT match_op_id, MAX(10*version+p1)-MAX(10*version) AS p1
FROM odds_op
GROUP BY match_op_id
```

This would work for `p1`s below up to 9. You need to add a zero to both `10`s in the query for every digit in your greatest `p1`

Answer (score 0):

This script is working on mysql. Hope this works on you too. Happy Coding!

```
SELECT o1.match_op_id, MAX(o1.p1) AS p1
FROM odds_op o1
INNER JOIN (
              SELECT match_op_id, MAX(version) AS version
              FROM odds_op
              GROUP BY match_op_id
           ) AS o2 ON o1.match_op_id = o2.match_op_id AND o1.version = o2.version
GROUP BY o1.match_op_id
```